# Formating SSD prior to install multiple OS

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd, format

Maybe it's a stupid question but is it possible to partition a brand new ssd 500Gb before installing any OS on it? 
I would like to install Win 7 64bit home premium and linux ubuntu or mint as the second OS. I also would like to have a data partition where my data would not been affected by any OS format operation.

And will the linux will make me a boot menu?

Thanks to help me out on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "is it possible to partition a brand new ssd 500Gb before installing any OS", do you mean partition using the Ubuntu installer, or more general? In fact the answer is yes in both cases. During install: see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation), if you'd like to partition prior to running the installer, take a look at a live CD/USB stick like [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org).

Regarding the data partition: since Windows can't (by default) read Linux Ext4 partitions, it's better to use NTFS (or FAT32) for it. Both Linux and Windows can read and write there.

If you install Windows first and Linux second, the installer will create a boot menu for you.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help me. I just want to know if it's possible to put partition 1 ntfs 2 ext4 3 swap and 4 ntfs (data partition for both systems) before installing any OS on the SSD and How to do it to have a boot menu on startup.

Comment: Yes, the partition order you propose is possible. Install Windows first, then Ubuntu Linux and use the manual partition method mentioned in the link in my answer. Then Ubuntu will add a start up menu for you.